# List of a type that is defined at runtime

Tags: c#

I am performing Automation using C# as programming language

I have an Enum holding columns in a table. I am holding datatype of these columns in "Description" for each of column name.

Each of the column is sortable, after sorting I want to verify the sort on specific column is correct. I am making a list of data in the column, sorting it programmatically and then sorting it on-screen, reading the content and then using List.SequenceEquals

I am trying to create a list of "type" (as specified in "Description"). But looks like I cannot create a List of runtime objects.

Any solution to this?

CODE

```
    {
    public enum tranColumns
    {
        [Description("DateTime")]
        InvoiceDate,
        [Description("string")]
        Customer,
        [Description("string")]
        InvoiceID,
        [Description("string")]
        LiabilityTypeDescription,
        [Description("string")]
        TransactionStatusDescription,
        [Description("string")]
        TestTransaction,
        [Description("string")]
        TransactionDate,
        [Description("int")]
        TransactionID,
        [Description("string")]
        SourceSystem,
        [Description("string")]
        ShipToGeocode,
        [Description("DateTime")]
        CreationTime
    }

var type = MyExtensions.GetDataType(tranColumns.InvoiceDate); //Gets System.Type

List<type> list= new List<type>();
}

        public static string GetEnumDescription(System.Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }

    public static Type GetDataType(System.Enum value)
    {
        switch(GetEnumDescription(value).ToLower())
        {
            case "datetime":
                return typeof(DateTime);
            case "string":
                return typeof(String);
            case "int":
                return typeof(Int32);
            default:
                Utilities.log("Unkwown datatype",LogType.ErrorEntry);
                return typeof(Object);
        }
    }
```

cannot create a list of "type" this way!

Comment: What does your `MyExtensions.GetDataType` method do?

Comment: It simply reads the description, uses a switch case and returns typeof(String) or typeof(DateTime) or typeof(Int32)

Comment: You should provide that code.  We don't know if it's bug free. You may, but we don't.

Comment: It seems like it might be simpler to use a `Dictionary<string, Type>`

Comment: added code for GetDataType

Comment: Lot of my code is dependent on these similar Enum. Making it a dictionary now might cause a lot of rework. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to rescue!

```
            var type = MyExtensions.GetDataType(column as Enum);

        DataTable dtAscen; //=logic to read table;
        List<object> listBeforeSort = (from x in dtAscen.AsEnumerable()
                            select (object)Convert.ChangeType(x.Field<string>(column.ToString()), type)).ToList();
        var temp = listBeforeSort.OrderBy(s => s);
        if(!listBeforeSort.SequenceEqual(temp))            
            Utilities.log("Issue with ascending sort on column " + column.ToString(), LogType.ErrorEntry);
```

Comment: Well, I am still curious how system works perfectly with this list<object> ! But hey, as long as this works with primitive type, I am happy..

Answer (score 5):

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
IList list= (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

You need to use IList.Add with object, because cast to List is not possible. I re-read you code and it seems that you can edit it and create the list in that way:

```
public static List<T> CreateMyList<T>(System.Enum value)
    {
        switch(GetEnumDescription(value).ToLower())
        {
            case "datetime":
                return new List<DateTime>();
            case "string":
                return new List<String>();
            case "int":
                return new List<Int32>();
            default:
                Utilities.log("Unkwown datatype",LogType.ErrorEntry);
                return new List<Object>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I add elements to this list? It looks like it accepts any "object" type.  I wont be able to ensure datatype and list.SequenceEquals(anotherList) wont be available

Comment: Thanks Radin, but it compiler complains it cannot convert List<DateTime> to List<T> implicitly. Also, I found a way around to this problem - LINQ to Rescue!

Answer (score 0):

You may need Activator.CreateInstance Method (Type)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
  string[] instances = instanceSpec.Split(';');
    Array instlist = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), instances.Length);
    object item;
    for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
    {
        // create the object from the specification string
        Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of: {0}", instances[i]);
        item = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(instances[i]));
        instlist.SetValue(item, i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nObjects and their default values:\n");
    foreach (object o in instlist)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type:     {0}\nValue:    {1}\nHashCode: {2}\n",
            o.GetType().FullName, o.ToString(), o.GetHashCode());
    }
```